Component is loading in a new page instead in the same page
I don't have much experience with frontend and I am facing a problem using Angular.
I have a page with a mat-sidenav-content and inside this content I want to load a component when I click to a link in my mat-sidenav .
The problem is, everytime that I click in a link in my sidenav, the component is not rendered inside the mat-sidenav-content, the content is load in another page.
I will let some code below of how I implemented that:
main-menu.component.html:
<mat-toolbar class="mat-elevation-z3">
    <button mat-icon-button (click)="collapsed.set(!collapsed())">
        <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <mat-label>My Financial Manager</mat-label>
    <span class="spacer"></span>
    <span>{{ currentDate | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy, HH:mm:ss' }}</span>
</mat-toolbar>
<mat-sidenav-container>
    <mat-sidenav opened mode="side" [style.width]="sideNavWidth()">
        <app-custom-sidenav [collapsed]="collapsed()"/>
    </mat-sidenav>
    <mat-sidenav-content class="content" [style.margin-left]="sideNavWidth()">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>        
    </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>

main-menu.component.css
.content{
  padding: 24px;
}

mat-toolbar{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
}

mat-sidenav-container{
  height: calc(100vh - 64px);
}

.spacer {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

main-menu.component.ts
import { Component, computed, OnInit, signal } from '@angular/core';
import { MenuService } from '../../services/main-menu/menu.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main-menu',
  templateUrl: './main-menu.component.html',
  styleUrl: './main-menu.component.css'
})
export class MainMenuComponent implements OnInit{

  user: any;
  currentDate: Date = new Date();
  collapsed = signal(false);
  sideNavWidth = computed(() => this.collapsed() ? '65px' : '250px');

  constructor(
    private menuService: MenuService
  ){}


  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.user = this.menuService.getUser();
    setInterval(() => {
      this.currentDate = new Date();
    }, 1000);
  }
}


custom-sidenav.component.html
<div class="sidenav-header">
    <img [width]="profilePicSize()" [height]="profilePicSize()" src="assets/images/profile.png" class="profile-picture">
    <div class="header-text" [class.hide-header-text]="sideNavCollapsed()">
        <h2>{{user.name}}</h2>
        <p>{{user.email}}</p>
    </div>
</div>

<mat-nav-list>
    <a 
    mat-list-item *ngFor="let item of menuItems()" 
    [routerLink]="item.route" 
    routerLinkActive
    #rla="routerLinkActive" 
    [activated]="rla.isActive">
        <mat-icon matListItemIcon>{{item.icon}}</mat-icon>
        <span matListItemTitle *ngIf="!sideNavCollapsed()">{{item.label}}</span>
    </a>
</mat-nav-list>

custom-sidenav.component.css
.profile-picture{
    border-radius: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.sidenav-header{
    padding-top: 24px;
    text-align: center;
}

.header-text{
    > h2{
        margin: 0;
        font-size: 1rem;
        line-height: 1.5rem;
    }

    > p {
        margin: 0;
        font-size: 0.8rem;
    }
}

.hide-header-text{
    opacity: 0;
    height: 0px;
}

custom-sidenav.component.ts
import { Component, computed, Input, signal, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MenuItem } from '../../../models/menu-type';
import { MenuService } from '../../../services/main-menu/menu.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-sidenav',
  templateUrl: './custom-sidenav.component.html',
  styleUrl: './custom-sidenav.component.css'
})
export class CustomSidenavComponent implements OnInit{

  user: any;

  sideNavCollapsed = signal(false);
  @Input() set collapsed(val: boolean){
    this.sideNavCollapsed.set(val)
  } 

  constructor(
    private menuService: MenuService
  ){}


  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.user = this.menuService.getUser();
  }

  menuItems = signal<MenuItem[]>([
    {
      icon: 'dashboard',
      label: 'Dashboard',
      route: 'dashboard',
    },
    {
      icon: 'account_balance_wallet',
      label: 'Cash control',
      route: 'cash-control',
    },
    {
      icon: 'trending_up',
      label: 'Investments',
      route: 'investments',
    }

  ]);

  profilePicSize = computed(() => this.sideNavCollapsed() ? '32' : '100');

  
}

app-routing.module.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { NewUserComponent } from './components/new-user/new-user.component';
import { MainMenuComponent } from './components/main-menu/main-menu.component';
import { InvestmentCreateComponent } from './components/investments/investment-create/investment-create.component';
import { InvestmentListComponent } from './components/investments/investment-list/investment-list.component';
import { CashControlCreateComponent } from './components/cash-control/cash-control-create/cash-control-create.component';
import { CashControlListComponent } from './components/cash-control/cash-control-list/cash-control-list.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './components/dashboard/dashboard.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full' ,component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'new-user', component: NewUserComponent },
  { path: 'home', component: MainMenuComponent },
  { path: 'investments/new', component: InvestmentCreateComponent },
  { path: 'home/investments', component: InvestmentListComponent },
  { path: 'cash-control/new', component: CashControlCreateComponent },
  { path: 'home/cash-control', component: CashControlListComponent },
  { path: 'home/dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }


I didnt try anything else, tryied ChatGPT and didn't work :D
How can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

please share a stackblitz or github repo where the issue happens, also share the contents of the file where the route loads, does it have a router-outlet?

Yes. I am using a router-outlet inside of a mat-sidenav-content at  main-menu.component.html. https://github.com/alanensina/my-financial-manager/

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
